# CAST to package type

Tags: oracle, user-defined-types

Is it possible to CAST to a type within a package?  For example:

```
CAST(v_variable AS Mypackage.type)
```

I know CAST states the ability to cast to built-in types but I was wondering if this was possible.  I'm interested in this approach because I prefer keeping my utilities in one package instead of having a separate TYPE object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  CAST() is a SQL function so we can only use it with SQL types.  This means we cannot use it with types we have declared in a PL/SQL package.